# Why don't we use generators with armatures with large diameters?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

From images of real-life generators they seem to have armatures that are not too large. However, from Faraday's law, shouldn't an armature with a larger diameter create a larger voltage?

Since Faraday's Law is

$V=N\frac{\Delta |BA|}{\Delta t}$

This means that the induced voltage should be large if the change in area (change in flux) is large.

Then in real life why don't we use very large armatures in generators? Wouldn't that increase the voltage produced as the flux changes from zero to very large?

Comment: Have you ever seen an armature in a hydroelectric plant?

Comment: Yes; I'm just wondering why they wouldn't be larger.